# Call custom SharePoint Service from Android

Tags: android, sharepoint-2010

I need to build an android application that will get information from SharePoint.

what is the best practice to make it? how to communicate with custom SharePoint service?

specially that i need to create my own (custom) SharePoint Service.

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint exposes a lot of its functionality through web services so you can send a web service call to one of many end points to pull back data.  Here is a list of the web services available in Sharepoint 2010:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Depending on what authentication method your Sharepoint site uses (Windows, Claims Based, Forms Based) you'll need to take different approaches on authentication before you're able to use the web services.  Here's an example of how to use Java to authenticate using Basic Authentication:

http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-java-tutorial/

There's also a Java to Sharepoint library on codeplex that you might be able to pull into your Android project.  If you can integrate this that would probably be your easiest option:

https://code.google.com/p/java-sharepoint-library/